# change color of a specific cell in a htmlTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I have a htmltable. Each of the cell of the table is identified by an ID, for example 0001 and so on. The table has not a fixed dimension, but dynamic, so there can be 20 or more cells depending on how much values are stored in the db. I would like to change the backgorund color of the textbox of a specific cell. But don't know how to access the cell.

I know this syntax:

```
// the whole background becomes green 
myTable.BgColor = "#008000"; 
// I see no changes
myTable.Rows[x].Column[y].BgColor = "#008000";


// I need a syntax like this
myTable.Cell(Id_cell).BgColor =  "#008000";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

.aspx:

```
<asp:Table ID="table" runat="server" />
```

C# Code:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Text = "Testing";
cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
row.Cells.Add(cell);
table.Rows.Add(row);

table.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background colour of an individual cell like this:

```
myTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].BgColor = "#553322";
```

Where 0 is the row number you want, in this case the first row and 1 is the cell number you want in this case the 2nd cell as indexes are based from 0. This has to be done before the table is rendered e.g. on page load.

You could generalise this to a method to set the cell colour for an id like so:

```
private void SetColorByCellId(HtmlTable table, string id, string color)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            if (table.Rows[i].Cells[j].ID == id)
            {
                table.Rows[i].Cells[j].BgColor = color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
SetColorByCellId(myTable, "0001", "#553322");
```

Comment: It seems a good idea, but table.Rows[i].Cells[j].ID returns me always null, why?